# Where to write the logic to upload FCM token or to subscribe to any topic while using FCM service with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to flutter and Firebase. I have registered my android app with firebase. My final goal is to send notifications to all the users automatically with a cloud function. So far, I know either I need to store the list of FCM tokens of all the users or subscribe them to perticular topic. I was thinking of going with subscribing to the topic, so that I will not have to store the tokens in my firestore. So, my question is where should I write

`FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("drawNotifications");`

Because, If I put it in the main or initState, then it will be called everytime the user runs the app and if I do so, is it the right way to?
Please feel free to let me know if I need to explain it more clearly as this is my very first question in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to give a user option to opt in to receive notifications. Prompt the user to get consent to receive notification and give an option to cancel at any point.

Although `subscribeToTopic` can be called multiple times from the same device within certain restrictions.

> The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/topic-messaging